# Scala: how to check if map has values greater than x?

Tags: scala

I was wondering what's the most efficient way to check if a map has a value equal or greater than a certain threshold:

for example, if I get the following map:

```
val x = Map(2 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 7 -> 1)
```

at the moment I wrote:

```
x.values.max > 2
```

Is there a more efficient way?
How to check if the Map contains a specific value instead?

Comment: `map.valuesIterator.exists(v => v > 2)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`scala.collection.Iterator.exists`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.1/scala/collection/Iterator.html#exists-fffff66f) to check whether there exists at least one item of a collection which satisfies a given predicate. To simplify iterating over the `Map`, you can use [`scala.collection.Map.valuesIterator`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.1.1/scala/collection/Map.html#valuesIterator-0):

```scala
x.valuesIterator.exists(_ > 2) //=> false
x.valuesIterator.exists(_ > 1) //=> true
```

[Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/jZt2uSc0RHudB7oXegklNQ/1)